# performing dispatch function when component unmounts using useEffect in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, dispatch

I want to perform a dispatch on the state items **only** when the component has been unmounted. So I tried this:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const store = useStore();
const state = store.getState();
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
       /* dispatch on state items code goes here */
    };
  }, []);
```

But doing the above, I cannot access the state and dispatch. So I added those two i.e state and dispatch on useEffect's dependency list. Now my code is:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const store = useStore();
const state = store.getState();
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
       /* dispatch on state items code goes here */
    };
  }, [dispatch, state]);
```

But now the problem is that the dispatch happens on every state change. I dont want the dispatch to occur on state change. I want it to occur on component unmount only.

Suggestions please!

Comment: Why does the first example doesn't work, I think the first one is correct.

Comment: the dispatch functions on the initial state i.e the state when the component was mounted which in my case will be an empty array. It does not disptach on the updated state. for e.g: i have this code inside the /* */:-  state.alertState.forEach((alert) => {
        dispatch(removeAlert(alert.id));
      });  removeAlert removes the state's alert object items by id.

Comment: Ok, i got it. I should place const state = store.getState() inside the returned function of useEffect. This way i will be getting updated value of state at the point when component unmounts.